# Is allocating new instance of Closeable to previously created instance, closing previous?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, autocloseable

For example `Scanner` class, which implements `Closeable` interface:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(...);
sc.//do smthing
sc = new Scanner(...); <- is previous Scanner closed? Does it create memory leak?
sc.//do smthing
sc.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you explicitly call `sc.close()`, or scope it in a [try-with-resources block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), there are no guarantees it will be closed. Some classes might have a finalizer or an associated [`Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html), but these are very unreliable (as in, you never know when or even if they will get called).